# Why are my python initiated cypher queries not abiding by verified uniqueness constraints and creating duplicate nodes?

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

Observation: Unique constraint not upheld through python until running same LOAD CSV query through the browser, after which python and browser both uphold uniqueness constraint.

I'm doing some testing on a local 3.5.4 community server db.  I am trying to load some nodes in the db by initiating a load csv and merge query.  I setup the unique constraint before doing so.  I've noticed that when doing this through python, it doesn't actually abide by the constraint.  I can validate the constraint command was accepted, but when I load another file it still duplicates nodes despite the constraint and the use of MERGE.

I notice that once I used the same exact LOAD CSV query directly in browser, it loads again with duplicates, but there after starts abiding by the constraint. Every LOAD CSV after that through the browser then blocks any new nodes based on the constraint. But running same query through python after that, then duplicates nodes even though it had just blocked them when running through the browser.

```
qry1 = "CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Import) ASSERT n.GUID IS UNIQUE"
qry2 = "LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///file.csv' AS f MERGE (:Import {ExternalId:f.ExternalId,NodeType:f.NodeType,GUID:f.GUID})"

#CREATE CONSTARINT
with neo_driver.session() as session:
    tx = session.begin_transaction()
    tx.run(qry1)
    tx.commit()

#CREATE NODES
with neo_driver.session() as session:
    tx = session.begin_transaction()
    tx.run(qry2)
    tx.commit()
```